# vue.js 2 on page back button pressed

Tags: vue.js

`<template> <childcomponent. v-for="i > 10" :key="i"></childcomponent>  </template>`

loading data on component created function. then user scroll to page down. everything is ok ...
but user goto another page on scroll position and then back the this page then page again load all data.. and goto page top.

I would like when user press the back button then goto same scroll position.  do you have any idea ?

thank you very much

I was test scrollbehaivor but not work..

```
<const scrollBehavior = function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (savedPosition) {
    // savedPosition is only available for popstate navigations.
    return savedPosition
  } else {
    const position = {}

    // scroll to anchor by returning the selector
    if (to.hash) {
      position.selector = to.hash

      // // specify offset of the element
      // if (to.hash === '#anchor2') {
      //   position.offset = { y: 100 }
      // }

      // bypass #1number check
      if (/^#\d/.test(to.hash) || document.querySelector(to.hash)) {
        return position
      }

      // if the returned position is falsy or an empty object,
      // will retain current scroll position.
      return false
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // check if any matched route config has meta that requires scrolling to top
      if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.scrollToTop)) {
        // coords will be used if no selector is provided,
        // or if the selector didn't match any element.
        position.x = 0
        position.y = 0
      }

      // wait for the out transition to complete (if necessary)
      this.app.$root.$once('triggerScroll', () => {
        // if the resolved position is falsy or an empty object,
        // will retain current scroll position.
        resolve(position)
      })
    })
  }
}
```